# OkHttp Post MediaType Parse

Tags: java, html, http, web, okhttp

I am trying to send a single line of text of a employee id in the body of a [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) POST request, simulating a request that I see using browser inspection.

The request is a mix of URL params and a single string of employee ID in the body of the post, i.e. `ABC123`

Currently after login and sending the request the server response is 500.

```
        Request quickFind = new Request.Builder()
            .url(quickFIndUrl)
            .addHeader("csrf_tok", csrfToken)
            .addHeader("x-rest-api", "true")
            .addHeader("x-requested-with", "true")
            .addHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
            .addHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Mobile Safari/537.36")
            .addHeader("accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
            .addHeader("origin", "https://contoso.com")
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
            .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown"), postBody))
            .build();
```

What does the line `.post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown"), postBody)` do as I think this might be the cause for server response 500.

On face value it looks the like it sets the `MIME type`, but then how is MIME type different to the `content-type` above?

What are valid types that can be parsed other than text/x-markdown?

Answer (score 1):

The content type on the request body will be transmitted as a `Content-Type` header.

You should remove the content-type header; it’s redundant.

Pick whichever content type best describes your request body.

Comment: Maybe - but I am seeing content-type header in the browser inspection.